# How to center vertically children of Box layout in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I would like to obtain such a layout, where all the images are centered vertically. For an example:

[image: Box layout centered vertically]

Here's how it looks in the code:

```
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(254.dp)
            .height(186.dp)
    ) {
        Image(
            // scaling
        )
        Image(
            // scaling, padding, zIndex
        )
        Image(
            // scaling, padding, zIndex
        )
        Image(
            // scaling, padding, zIndex
        )
        Image(
            // padding, zIndex
        )
    }
```

`Box` layout gives possibility to align items inside a bit:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically) 
    // But doesn't compile, type mismatch: `Alignment.Horizontal` type is required.
    // Not `Alignment.Vertical`.
)
```

or

```
Box(
     contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
     // But doesn't compile, type mismatch: `Alignment` type is required.
     // Not `Alignment.Vertical`.
)
```

But it doesn't compile. If none of the above even compiles, then what should I do? There's no alignment function available for `Box`, which supports `Alignment.CenterVertically`...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It turned out, the solution is to not even bother to use `Alignment.CenterVertically`, but `Alignment.CenterStart`.

```
Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart,
    ...
)
```

What a surprise. It kinda makes sense, although naming is confusing if you worked with standard non-compose Android Layouts before.

As it turns out, `Alignment.CenterVertically` is useful for `Row` layout and its `verticalAlignment` parameter:

```
Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter // for horizontally center

contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart // for vertically center

contentAlignment = Alignment.Center   // for both
```